# addLoadEvent can't call the function

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the result of alert undefined but not 6？I think the function addLoadEvent works well，and so does the alert

```js
function addLoadEvent(func){
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if(typeof oldonload != 'function'){
    window.onload = func;
  }else{
    window.onload = function(){
    oldonload();
    func();
    }
  }
}
function a(){
  return 6;
}
alert(addLoadEvent(a))
```

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: `addLoadEvent` doesn't actually return anything, so this is why you are getting `undefined`. For the effect you want, you need to either to do `alert(6)` inside `a()` (you're not actually using the return  value). Either that or put the alert inside `addLoadEvent`

Answer (score 0):

`addLoadEvent` has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

It is `a` that returns `6`, but you aren't logging the return value of `a` (which isn't available until after the `load` event fires, which is [too late](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) to capture it at the point you are trying to).